# LINQ order outer list by property of inner list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq

I would like to sort a collection of `Method` objects based on the `OtherName` property of the first element of each object's `Method2` collection.

```
public class Method
{
    public IEnumerable<Method2> Method2{ get; set; }
}

public class Method2
{
    public string OtherName {get;set;}
}
```

Code

```
// generate test data
var rnd = new Random();
var collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(x => {
   var m = new Method();
   m.Method2 = new Method2[] { new Method2 { OtherName = rnd.Next(10).ToString() } };
   return m;
});

// sort outer list by OtherName property of first element in inner list
// ??????
```

Comment: Method.Method2.OrderBy(n => n.Name).ToList();

Comment: Please provide an [mcve], it's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? What results do you get and what do you expect instead?

Comment: Hi, @GlennvanAcker Thanks for the reply. My Method is an array, I couldn't do Method.Method2 directly.

Comment: I don't get it. You class method has a single ID and name and contains a List of method two, which means a list of IDs and names? Where is the relation? Shouldn't there be two lists in parallel with unique IDs? Is there a list of Method one and each item contains the full Method2 list?

Comment: @nvoigt, Hi, I added some code inside.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I was unable to sort the list using inner list.

Comment: @Mihaeru, Hi, I have updated my question.

Comment: You may have to flatten the list first using `SelectMany`

Comment: You can use LinqDyncamic and pass the name as string to the order by. 
You can use the ThenBy() to sort with all the properties.

Comment: @DStanley always using the first item, because query2 will be ordered by default using the sql from DB and return to code level

Comment: `I was unable to sort the list using inner list` - what property of the inner list should the outer list item be sorted on? Its length? Some property of one of its items? Which item?

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner, use the first item from the inner list for outer list to sort.

Comment: You write that Method2 contains contains an array? ...or is an array? In your code it isn't. And what do you want to use for sorting? Name in method2? Which one? For each item in Method list you have a list of Method2. Are they all the same? And on what do you want to sort?
The only thing which might make sense is, that Method2 list is the same for all Method items and that you handle the relation based on the IDs. Do you want to sort Method2 and then, based on the Sorted Method2, you want to sort Method list by the common IDs?

Comment: @Mihaeru Yes, First I would like to sort out Method2, but it already sorted by default using the SQL that I query out from DB, the result will be like `Before Sort in my question`. Then after that, I would like to sort the MethodList. But how to sort using common IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote you want this:

> use the first item from the inner list for outer list to sort

```
var sorting = methodList.OrderBy(x => x.Method2.FirstOrDefault()?.OtherName).ToList();
```

Comment: possible null reference exception in there, I'd use `....FirstOrDefault()?.OtherName`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you saved my day.

Comment: @Grimm Yep, Thank You and Thanks everyone for helping this question.

Comment: @Mihaeru I have 1 more question, I dig further, how if I want to use the whole Method2List item for outer list to sort, any answer for that? I might be using that too.

Comment: For example, In this case, how do you sort it? 
`
[A,C]
[A]
[A,D]
[Z,E]
`
to 
`
[A]
[A,C]
[A,E]
[Z,E]
`

Comment: Not sure if I understand but maybe that will be what you want: `var sorting = methodList.OrderBy(x => x.Method2.OrderBy(m2 => m2.OtherName).FirstOrDefault()?.OtherName).ToList();`

Comment: @Mihaeru I have tried this method, I've got this result `[A][A,C][A][A,E]` instead of `[A][A][A,C][A,E]`. Or I need order by Count of the array first and then perform the sorting?

Comment: I got the solution btw, order by count first then perform sorting.

Comment: Hm. I guess your idea will not be very reliable but I guess I know now what you want. Unfortunately I cannot test it. Try this:
`var sorted = methodList.OrderBy(x => x.Method2.OrderBy(m2 => m2.OtherName).Select(n => n.OtherName).Aggregate((i, j) => i + j));`
This sorts the Method2 names and combines them to one string, which can then be used for sorting the Method list. At least, that's my idea :)

Comment: Noted, my code is

`var orderByCount = methodList.OrderBy(x => x.Method2.OrderBy(n => n.OtherName).Count()).ToList();

var sorting = orderByCount .OrderBy(x => x.Method2.FirstOrDefault()?.OtherName).ToList();`

Maybe performance-wise is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To sort by the "first" ordered item in the sub-list use `First`:

```
var sorting = methodList.OrderBy(x => x.Method2
                                       .OrderBy(n => n.Name)
                                       .FirstOrDefault())
                        .ToList();
```

If `Method2` is already sorted then you can just take out the inner 'OrderBy'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, I'm unable to sort the MethodList ascendingly. Kindly view my example output.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not sure what you mean. Are you trying to sore `methoifList` in-place? The sorted list will be in another variable, but you can overwrite the variable by using `methodList = methodList.OrderBy(...` instead.

Comment: How does this sort for every name in the Method2 List?

Comment: While I like rep as much as anyone, this question simply isn't ready for an answer yet!

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner i am not sure how to resolve this either.

Comment: @Anonymous maybe you need to rethink this.This does not make sense. Sorry no Solution to your problem

Comment: According to the last comment on the Q by the OP, this is the right answer if you remove the inner `OrderBy`.  (OP makes no mention of a requirement to sort the inner list, just use the first item).  You might also offer some insight into the differences between `First` and `FirstOrDefault`